# waiting on 2 (or more) async generators simultaneously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, generator, yield

I've been struggling with this for a while.

How would you write a async generator that, given n async generators, yields the values from the n generators, in the order in which they arrived.

The method should be in the format:
`const merged =  merge([gen1, gen2,...])`

for example:

```
gen1 and gen2 are async generators.
gen1() yields 2 values: 1 in 100ms, 3 in 300ms  
gen2() yields 2 values: 2 in 200ms, 4 in 400ms

merge([gen1, gen2]) will yield 1, 2, 3, 4 (in that order, every 100ms)
```

Comment: Hard! Feels like `Promise.race` could be the right tool?

Comment: I tried that! This is so hard :) I've been trying for days

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So... After, literally, days of trying to solve this.
This works (just copy paste into latest chrome with experimental flag turned on)

```
function timer(time = 500) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), time));
}

async function* gen1() {
  await timer(100);
  yield 1;
  await timer(300);
  yield 4;
}

async function* gen2() {
  await timer(200);
  yield 2;
  await timer(100);
  yield 3;
}

function race(promises) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    promises.forEach((p, index) => {
      p.then(value => {
        resolve({index, value});
      });
    })
  );
}
async function* mergen(...gens) {
  let promises = gens.map((gen, index) =>
    gen.next().then(p => ({...p, gen}))
  );

  while (promises.length > 0) {
    yield race(promises)
    .then(({index, value: {value, done, gen}}) => {
      promises.splice(index, 1);
      if (!done)
        promises.push(
          gen.next().then(({value: newVal, done: newDone}) => ({
            value: newVal,
            done: newDone,
            gen
          }))
        );
      return value;
    });
  }
}

async function printGen(gen) {
  let max = 10;
  for await (x of gen) {
    if (x) console.log('Next up:', x);
    if (--max <= 0) break;
  }
}

printGen(mergen(gen1(), gen2())); // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

It's pre-refactoring, so bare in mind it's not nice and clean yet.
The interesting code is called `mergen()` (get it? merge-gen?)
It uses a modified version of `Promise.race()` included here as well. 
The reason for the use of a modified `race` is because I needed to have the index of the promise that finished first.

**UPDATE:** And now it's an npm module https://github.com/hesher/mergen